# JavaScript “map” function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, map-function

Looking at the [`map` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in JavaScript, what am I doing wrong here?

```js
// Input: [ { name: "Kevin"}, { name: "Bob" } ]
// Output: [ { "Kevin" :0 }, { "Bob": 1 } ]
var map = function(arr, property) {
  var i = 0;
  var m = arr.prototype.map(makeKv);

  // Input: { name: "Kevin" }
  // Output: { "Kevin" = i } // GLOBAL
  
  function makeKv(item) {
    return {
      item: i++
    };
  };

  console.log("m : " + m);
};
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/FgdSj/2)

Please also help me get rid of the **global**, too.

Comment: Note, I updated to include `var i = 0;` per a user's comment. Thanks to that user, but still getting no output. http://jsfiddle.net/FgdSj/1/

Comment: You never call map() in your fiddle

Comment: As an aside - I meant to originally create this - http://jsfiddle.net/9U2GK/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

First,

```
var m = arr.prototype.map(makeKv);
```

You don't need `prototype` here.  You only use that when you are using the constructor, like `Array.prototype.map`.  Here, you just need to do `arr.map`.

Second,

```
function makeKv(item) {
    return {item: i++};
};
```

You never declare `i` anywhere.  How can you add one to something that doesn't exist.  You need to have `var i = 0;` before this.

Finally, `return {item: i++};` will make a key called *literally* `"item"`.  You need to declare the object first (`var ret = {};`), then use `[item]` to set the value.

`Array.map`'s callback is passed the element in the array as the 1st parameter, so `item` will be an object.  You need to do `item[property]` to get the value you want.

P.S. Don't do `"m : " + m` in your `console.log`, that will concat strings, thus converting `m` to a string.  Use `,` instead: `console.log("m : ", m);`

So, all together, try:

```
var map = function(arr, property) { 
    var i = 0;        
    var m = arr.map(makeKv);

    function makeKv(item) {
        var ret = {};
        ret[item[property]] = i++;
        return ret;
    };

    console.log("m : ", m);
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/FgdSj/3/

**EDIT**: `Array.map`'s callback is passed the index in the array as the 2nd parameter, so `var i = 0;` isn't needed here:

```
var map = function(arr, property) {      
    var m = arr.map(makeKv);

    function makeKv(item, index) {
        var ret = {};
        ret[item[property]] = index;
        return ret;
    };

    console.log("m : ", m);
}
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/FgdSj/5/

Answer (score 1):

```
arr.prototype.map(makeKv);
```

should be

```
arr.map(makeKv);
```

Now you have another issue since it will return

```
[ { item : 0}, { item : 1} ]
```

If you change the mapped function to

```
function makeKv(item) {
    var x = {}
    x[item.name] = i++;        
    return x;
};
```

it would give you what you want.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qMuR4/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still getting no output in console - http://jsfiddle.net/FgdSj/2/.

Comment: @KevinMeredith: You are aware you never actually *call* `map()`, right?

Answer (score 1):

Just call `.map` directly

```
arr.map(makeKv)
```

I, for whatever reason (maybe `map` is overridden), you want to use the `Array.prototype`'s method

```
[].map.call(arr, makeKv);
```

---

Here's, it's all fixed up for you to match your desired output

```
// input: [{name: "Kevin"}, {name: "Bob"}], "name"
var map = function(arr, property) { 
    var i = 0; 

    function makeKv(item) {
        var obj = {};
        obj[item[property] = i++;
        return obj;
    };

    return arr.map(makeKv);
}

var result = map([{name: "Kevin"}, {name: "Bob"}], "name");
console.log(result);
// [{"Kevin" : 0}, {"Bob" : 1}];
```

Comment: `arr.prototype` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
var map = function(arr, property) { 
    var i = 0; 
    var m = Array.prototype.map(makeKv);

    // input: {name: "Kevin"}
    // output: "Kevin" = i // GLOBAL
    function makeKv(item) {
        return {item: i++};
    };

    console.log("m : " + m);
    return m;
}

map();
```